# How to add two <li> in right of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar with some `<li>` at it.

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  navbar-centered" role="navigation">
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
            <img src="~/Images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
            <li class="hidden">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

I need to add there two `<li>`, but it need to be at right of navbar.

Something like this:

[image: screenshot]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  navbar-centered" role="navigation">
 <div class="container" style="position: relative">
   <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
        <img src="~/Images/logo.png" /></a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:left">
        <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
        <li class="hidden">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Benefits</a>
        </li>
        <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
            <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <ul style="float:right">
      <li><a>Try it Risk free</a></li>
      <li><a>login</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another `<ul>` element with `navbar-right` class to it

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top  navbar-centered" role="navigation">
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
            <img src="~/Images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
            <li class="hidden">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Benefits</a>
            </li>
            <li style="margin-left: 35px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
        //this is the nav elments towards right
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Right Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Right Link 2</a></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex on the Nav

```
CSS
ul.nav{
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
ul.nav li.right{
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

HTML
ul.nav
  li*3 // normal links 
  li.right*2 // sign up links
```